# A bound on a sum

Tags: inequality

Suppose there exist $2k$ integers $\displaystyle i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k$ and $\displaystyle j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_k$, of values in $\{1,2,\ldots,1000\}$. These integers are not necessarily distinct.
For any non-negative real numbers $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_{1000}$ satisfying $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{1000}=1$, find the maximum positive integer $k$ for which the following inequality holds
$$\displaystyle a_{i_1}a_{j_1}+a_{i_2}a_{j_2} +\cdots +a_{i_k}a_{j_k}\leq \frac{1}{2.014}$$
This problem resists all attacks I have tried. The fact that there might be repetitions is what mainly stopped me from reaching anything meaningful. Thanks for any and all help.
Also I have a question, $2.014$ is obviously a Red Herring, what constant can we put? Though this is not important. And for the correctness of the question, this is an olympiad question. Thanks everyone again.

Comment: What is your reference? Can you attach a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3354443&sid=b97db1d7fe5b14a20dd2079d05f84772#p3354443
It is from this site, here it is given it is from Japan Olympiad.

Comment: With reference to my solution, I believe the problem is stated incorrectly. Can you find the original reference?

Comment: I can try but not sure. Thanks for disproving it sir.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem right to me.

Take $k=1$ (or anything larger), and the integers $ i_1 = 1, j_1 = 1$ (and anything else).

For the non-negative real numbers $a_1 = 1, a_i = 0 \forall i \neq 1$.

Then, it is not true that $ \sum a_{i_x} a_{j_x} \leq \frac{1}{2.014}$.